Bootstrap error ??? $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color
ive been working on this project for a while now and everything has been working fine and then all the sudden i start getting this error. im not sure why its happening because i did not touch the styles file at all and ive tried everything to fix it.
Application bundle generation failed. [2.011 seconds]

✘ [ERROR] $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
    ╷
166 │ $link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
    │                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  src/scss/_bootstrap-variables.scss 166:29  @import
  src/scss/adminlte.scss 11:9                @import
  src/styles.scss 10:9                       root stylesheet [plugin angular-sass]

    angular:styles/global:styles:1:8:
      1 │ @import 'src/styles.scss';

this is what my styles.scss looks like:
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700');
@import url('https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/css/flag-icon.min.css');

@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr';

@import './scss/adminlte.scss';

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

// Sidebar menu animation
// Needed for open/close menu animation for menus with child nodes
.nav .nav-item:not(.menu-open) > .ng-trigger-openClose,
.nav .nav-item > .ng-trigger-openClose.ng-animating {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

// Override original AdminLTE transform
.nav-sidebar .menu-is-opening > .nav-link i.right,
.nav-sidebar .menu-is-opening > .nav-link svg.right,
.nav-sidebar .menu-open > .nav-link i.right,
.nav-sidebar .menu-open > .nav-link svg.right {
    transform: none;
}


this is my _bootstrap-variables.scs:

$link-color:                theme-color("primary") !default;
$link-decoration:           none !default;
$link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
$link-hover-decoration:     none !default;


my adminlte.scss:
/*!
 *   AdminLTE v3.2.0
 *   Author: Colorlib
 *   Website: AdminLTE.io <https://adminlte.io>
 *   License: Open source - MIT <https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT>
 */

// Bootstrap
// ---------------------------------------------------
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'bootstrap-variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// Variables and Mixins
// ---------------------------------------------------
@import 'variables';
@import 'variables-alt';
@import 'mixins';

@import 'parts/core';
@import 'parts/components';
@import 'parts/extra-components';
@import 'parts/pages';
@import 'parts/plugins';
@import 'parts/miscellaneous';


ive tried to delete and reinstall bootstrap, ive tried rearranging the imports like i saw some forums suggest...

You must import Bootstrap variables before your overrides.
